# Getting node.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I keep getting this error. Whats does it even mean?:
I useless with coding so please help me out :)

Greetings

```
 logon fail: 65, sessionID: 6343803
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Logon fail: 65
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (C:
sgo.ru\Bot\node_modules\steam\lib\handlers\user.js:1
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (C:\Users\GiimpeN
e_modules\steam\lib\steam_client.js:106:26)
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (C:
sgo.ru\Bot\node_modules\steam\lib\steam_client.js:19
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (C:\Users\GiimpeN
e_modules\steam\lib\steam_client.js:106:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Connection._readPacket (C:\Users\GiimpeN\Desk
ules\steam\lib\connection.js:50:8)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:424:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:418:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:174:11)
```

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd suggest you read this [How to I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which might help you next time.

Comment: "Error: Logon fail: 65"  so find the line where happens logon procedure and debug it or show us Your code.

Comment: Here is the code http://ge.tt/3GFp1xM2/v/0

Answer (score 0):

You have an error that has been thrown and not catch, so the js engine will stop the execution. Other than that, without any code, it will be impossible to debug.

Comment: Okey. So could you maybe look over it to help me?

Comment: @PontusMathisen - The requirement here is that you include the relevant code IN your question.  Without it, we can really only make wild guesses as to what might be wrong and many times, we can't even do that much.  You HAVE to include the relevant code IN your question.

Comment: What you have provided is not even close to be "code"

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of an event named `"error"` being emitted from an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).  This is a special case - if an EventEmitter emits an error event and there are no listeners for that event, it will throw an error.